# Javascript: NaN vs typeof Number

Tags: javascript

I need to check a value is a number. I have two solutions:

```
typeof input !== 'number'
```

and

```
isNaN(input)
```

What is the difference. Who choose one over the other?

Comment: `isNaN` which stands for `is Not a Number` does actually _not_ check whether the value passed is not of type `number`, it checks for the special value `NaN`.

Comment: isNaN('a') is true
isNaN(1) is false

So it looks to me like it tries to turn 'a' into a number, if it cant it becomes NaN.

Comment: `typeof NaN === "number"` btw

Comment: Number as in digit or number as in type? You've provided two different functions with two different meanings here.

Comment: I now see. A string containing a number is false if isNaN is used. Yet with type of matches the type as well.

Comment: Thanks that helps.

Comment: `Number.isNaN` checks for `NaN`, the global `isNaN` checks, whether the value converted to number is `NaN`, which can often be [surprising](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#confusing_special-case_behavior).